# Another probability word problem

Tags: probability

Again, forgive me if this is basic:

> Assume you are taking two courses this semester (A and B). The probability that you will pass course A is 0.835 and the probability that you will pass both courses is 0.276. The probability that you will pass at least one of the courses is 0.981. What is the probability that you will pass course b?

So I figure out (0.835 - 0.276 (both)) is .559 and then because of the wording I assume I'm doing the addition law again so I do 0.835 + .559 - 0.981 to arrive at 0.413.

Is this logic correct?

Comment: It's been a while, but isn't the probability of two independent events both happening the multiplication of the individual probabilities?

Comment: I believe so but I didn't know if the multiplication rule was in place in here.

Comment: @abiessu:  but we are not given that the events are independent, and we have enough information not to make that assumption.

Comment: @Rossmillikan: good point; and seeing the correct answer shows that the events cannot be independent because the alternate-class probability is too large

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:  $0.559$ is the chance you will pass $A$ only.  I don't understand your second calculation.  If you draw a Venn diagram, you have the values in three of the four regions, missing only the chance that you pass $B$ only.  If you deduct the two that involve failing $B$ from $1$ you are there.

Comment: Simple and easy answer. Thanks.